# How to store connected users with passport across server reboot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am playing with `passport-local`. Its use is very straightforward, however the way passport establishes the relation between the cookie-session-id and the connected user is still mysterious to me.

I would like to store on a database the connected sessions in order to:

- Know the connected users
- Detect IP changes (for security reasons)
- Auto disconnect users not seen for a long time
- Change the session number across each request (for security reasons)
- Keep the users connected across server reboot (useful for debugging, and server update)

From this not-working snippet below, you can see I have two collections:

- One to store the registered users
- One to store the connected users

Here the snippet:

```
import passport from 'passport'
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local'

import mongoose from 'mongoose'

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,    
  password: String
})

var Sessions = new mongoose.Schema({
  session: String, // Sessions of connected users 
  username: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  ip: String, // IP of the connected user 
  lastSeen: Date, // When the user made his last request 
})

var User = mongoose.model('UserSchema')
```

How should I proceed to populate the Session table with `passport`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I understood and I should be able to answer my own question.

### Passport is not guilty

Passport is not responsible for persistence, but `express.session` is. Passport adds a wrapper in the *middleware* to intercept HTTP requests and populate the request with methods and attributes such as `LogOut` or `username`.

By default `express.session` stores data into memory so this data is destroy when the server is stopped. Passport stores only one field into the session:

```
{ passport: { user: 'user-id' }}
```

Now we exonerated Passport, we can focus on the sessions.

### Sessions

Express session automatically creates a cookie with a signed `sid` made from the secret:

app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
  })

This `sid` is the cookie id and it is used by `express.session` to link session data (stored on the server only), with the request made from the client.

### Persistent session

To achieve what you wanna do (... What I would like to do), you have to make the session persistent. If you which to use MongoDB, you can use `connect-mongo` which store session data into a Mongo collection:

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express.session);
```

var app = express();

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.session({     
    secret: 'keyboard cat', 
    rolling: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://localhost/db', stringify: false })
  }));
  //...
}
```

When you start your server and someone make a request, it will add an entry into the db collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "AcBXmfIXvz_y2Jp4nw1zfJvZTVPsCq7D", 
    "session" : {
        "cookie" : {
            "originalMaxAge" : null, 
            "expires" : null, 
            "secure" : null, 
            "httpOnly" : true, 
            "domain" : null, 
            "path" : "/"
        }, 
        "passport" : {
            "user" : NumberInt(1)
        }
    }, 
    "expires" : ISODate("2018-06-03T18:10:54.237+0000")
}
```

You can see that Passport only store the user id as explained.

### In summary

> Know the connected users

Now, you have this information in MongoDB. However when a user disconnects, the data session will remains in the database. You may use the compatibility mode:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({
      url: 'mongodb://localhost/test-app',
      autoRemove: 'interval',
      autoRemoveInterval: 10 // In minutes. Default
    })
}));
```

To automatically remove expired session from the database.

> Detect IP changes (for security reasons)

You have to store this information into your session with:

```
req.session.ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
     req.connection.remoteAddress ||
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress).split(",")[0];
```

> Auto disconnect users not seen for a long time

You have to implement that manually. You can use an `event` from MongoStore such as `touch` triggered when a session has been touched.

> Change the session number across each request (for security reasons)

This is more complicated and I don't have the answer yet. Changing the cookie `sid` across connections means to regenerate a new session id and update the MongoDB. I don't have a working solution yet.

> Keep the users connected across server reboot (useful for debugging, and server update)

Well, it works thanks to `connect-mongo`